# Is $n2^n= O(e^n)$

Tags: calculus, limits

In order to see if $n2^n= O(e^n)$ I want to use the limit technique. But I don't know how to calculate  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n2^n}{e^n}$

Can anyone please help me to see what is the result of this limit?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, notice that we can rewrite the limit as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n2^n}{e^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n$$
and intuitively notice that a linear function does not outpace the exponential decay of $\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^{n}$.  What should the limit be?

Comment: So the limit will equal to 0, right?

Comment: @Taban Correct.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate method (l'Hôpital):
$$
\frac{n2^n}{e^n} = \frac{n}{(e/2)^n}
$$
has indeterminate form $\frac\infty\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  Differentiate numerator and denominator to get
$$
\frac{1}{(e/2)^n\log(e/2)}
$$
which has form $\frac{1}{\infty}$ and therefore converges to $0$.  Thus, the original also converges to $0$.